# Finding all chemical symbols in a file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file containing many chemical formulas throughout. I need to mark any text that is a chemical formula. I want to search a file for any place containing a combination of at least one chemical symbol and at least one number, and add `\chemical{}` around it. E.g. `H2O` becomes `\chemical{H2O}` and `FeS2` becomes `\chemical{FeS2}`.

- The chemicals are bounded by spaces () or forward-slashes (`/"`. E.g.: `/Ar` becomes `/\chemical{Ar}`, but `Arizona` should not be identified as ` \chemical{Ar}izona".
- Combinations containing no numbers should be ignored.
- I found this list which I think has every possible chemical name: "Ac, Ag, Al, Am, Ar, As, At, Au, B, Ba, Be, Bh, Bi, Bk, Br, C, Ca, Cd, Ce, Cf, Cl, Cm, Cn, Co, Cr, Cs, Cu, Db, Ds, Dy, Er, Es, Eu, F, Fe, Fm, Fr, Ga, Gd, Ge, H, He, Hf, Hg, Ho, Hs, I, In, Ir, K, Kr, La, Li, Lr, Lu, Md, Mg, Mn, Mo, Mt, N, Na, Nb, Nd, Ne, Ni, No, Np, O, Os, P, Pa, Pb, Pd, Pm, Po, Pr, Pt, Pu, Ra, Rb, Re, Rf, Rg, Rh, Rn, Ru, S, Sb, Sc, Se, Sg, Si, Sm, Sn, Sr, Ta, Tb, Tc, Te, Th, Ti, Tl, Tm, U, Uuh, Uuo, Uup, Uuq, Uus, Uut, V, W, Xe, Y, Yb, Zn, Zr".

How can I find all of the chemical formulas appearing in the file?

Comment: How about a plain regex? It should match a space delimited token containing `(chemicalsymbol digit*)+`, where chemicalsymbol is any element on the list you provided.

Comment: @calin Presumably he doesn't want to go write nearly the same regex  118 times.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use Perl.  It is more monotonous than exciting.  You create a regex containing all the alternative symbols, and then build up a more complex regex from that and some other bits and pieces:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $symbols = "Ac|Ag|Al|Am|Ar|As|At|Au|B|Ba|Be|Bh|Bi|Bk|Br|C|Ca|Cd|Ce|Cf|Cl|Cm|Cn|Co|Cr|Cs|Cu|Db|Ds|Dy|Er|Es|Eu|F|Fe|Fm|Fr|Ga|Gd|Ge|H|He|Hf|Hg|Ho|Hs|I|In|Ir|K|Kr|La|Li|Lr|Lu|Md|Mg|Mn|Mo|Mt|N|Na|Nb|Nd|Ne|Ni|No|Np|O|Os|P|Pa|Pb|Pd|Pm|Po|Pr|Pt|Pu|Ra|Rb|Re|Rf|Rg|Rh|Rn|Ru|S|Sb|Sc|Se|Sg|Si|Sm|Sn|Sr|Ta|Tb|Tc|Te|Th|Ti|Tl|Tm|U|Uuh|Uuo|Uup|Uuq|Uus|Uut|V|W|Xe|Y|Yb|Zn|Zr";

#my $symbols = "Ac|Ag|Al|...|Y|Yb|Zn|Zr";

my $regex = qr{ ([/ ]) ( (?:$symbols) (?: \d (?:$symbols) )* \d? ) ([ /]) }x;

printf "$regex\n";

while (<>)
{
    s/$regex/$1\\chemical{$2}$3/g;  # Handles first and third (, ...) in H2O CO2 H2SO4
    s/$regex/$1\\chemical{$2}$3/g;  # Handles second (fourth, ...)
    print $_;
}
```

The first capture deals with the space or slash before the symbol.  The second capture is gruesome, using the humungous string in `$symbols` twice.  The `(?:...)` are purely for grouping, not capture.  The pattern looks for a chemical symbol, optionally followed by zero or more sequences of a digit and another symbol, possibly with a trailing digit.  Note that this is what you specified, but will miss compounds such as H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>, CO<sub>2</sub>, KMnO<sub>4</sub>, and so on.  You can pick those up with a simple adaptation:

```
my $regex = qr{ ([/ ]) ( (?:$symbols) (?: \d* (?:$symbols) )* \d* ) ([ /]) }x;
```

I'm also assuming single digits in all compounds.  That works for many, but some of the longer hydrocarbons won't be so good: CH<sub>4</sub>, C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>6</sub>, C<sub>3</sub>H<sub>8</sub>, C<sub>4</sub>H<sub>10</sub>, ...  Again, you can deal with that by replacing the 0-or-1 `?` with 0-or-more `*`.  You still have problems with commas after compounds in lists, compounds at the beginning of a line, compounds at the end of a line, etc — your specification rules them all out.

You might do better replacing the first and third captures with `\b` to mark the boundary between 'words' and 'non-words', where a chemical symbol would count as a word.  This deals with the issues with commas and beginning and end of line, but picks up more than you specified.

```
my $regex = qr{ \b ( (?:$symbols) (?: \d* (?:$symbols) )* \d* ) \b }x;

printf "$regex\n";

while (<>)
{
    s/$regex/\\chemical{$1}/g;
    print $_;
}
```

Note that this formulation doesn't need the double substitution; a single one is sufficient, so it is definitely cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
  strElements="Ac Ag Al Am Ar As At Au B Ba Be Bh Bi Bk Br C Ca Cd Ce Cf Cl Cm Cn Co Cr Cs Cu Db Ds Dy Er Es Eu F Fe Fm Fr Ga Gd Ge H He Hf Hg Ho Hs I In Ir K Kr La Li Lr Lu Md Mg Mn Mo Mt N Na Nb Nd Ne Ni No Np O Os P Pa Pb Pd Pm Po Pr Pt Pu Ra Rb Re Rf Rg Rh Rn Ru S Sb Sc Se Sg Si Sm Sn Sr Ta Tb Tc Te Th Ti Tl Tm U Uuh Uuo Uup Uuq Uus Uut V W Xe Y Yb Zn Zr"
  n = split(strElements, arrElements)
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    hashElements[arrElements[i]] = 1}
  {for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    str = substr($i, 1, 1) == "/" ? substr($i, 2) : $i
    n = split(str, elements, "[0123456789]+")
    while (n > 0) {if (!(elements[n] in hashElements)) break; n--}
    if (n == 0)
      $i = (substr($i, 1, 1) == "/" ? "/" : "") "\\chemical{" str "}"
    }
  print}' your_file
```

The idea of the script is the following:

1. Build a hash of all elements (in `awk`, arrays are associative).
2. For each line, take one word at a time, split it by number, and see if each subword is an element.
3. If it is the case, surround the chemical with the wanted string.

Of course, some logic need to be added to consider the special character `/`.